# Black screen after Grub2 menu with Live USB on Acer E15 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, acer, windows-10

I just bought an Acer Aspire E15 (E5 573G-71L9) with an NVIDIA Geforce 940M, Intel Core i7-5500U processor, 15.6'' FHD LED LCD, and Windows 10 Home pre-installed. The default boot method is UEFI - Secure Boot.

I created 700 GB free disk space by shrinking the Windows partition in Windows 10. I created a bootable USB stick using the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu with an ISO of Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit (the checksum is correct).

After having changed the boot order to have the USB stick first, I got the GRUB2 menu. After selecting 'Trying Ubuntu without installing', I got a blank/black screen. The 'working light' on the USB stick did not flash anymore, indicating that nothing was happening.

I tried the following proposed fixes, without success:
- Replacing 'quiet splash' with 'nomodeset' (assuming it was the graphic card)
- Using an external monitor (for the same reason, using both 'quiet splash' and 'nomodeset')
- Setting the boot method to 'Legacy' (no valid boot device was found)
- Disabling 'secure boot' in UEFI (still blank screen after grub)
- Adding the two files in BOOT/EFI (or was it EFI/BOOT..) to trusted boot methods and putting them on top of the boot order (still blank screen after grub)

With that, it looks like I covered virtually all suggestions given in 'similar questions' and I have no clue how to continue. Suggestions, pointers to similar questions that I may have missed and other help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1 January 2016**: in addition, I tried to run the live USB of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Mint 17.3 (normal and compatibility mode). I also burned Ubuntu 15.10 on a DVD. In all cases, after having selected an option from the menu, I got a black screen. Both the CPU and the graphic card are used in 'Ubuntu certified systems'.

Are there any tests that I can carry out to find the probable cause of the black screen?

Comment: Do you mean Syslinux menu? GRUB2 does not (or should not) show up when booting the Live system.

Comment: I did mean the Grub2 menu (the purple menu) that allows users to choose between 'Trying Ubuntu without installing' and 'Install Ubuntu'.  As far as I know, this is the normal menu when booting from a Live USB - I have seen this, and used this, several times before on different notebooks (without UEFI, though).  On one occasion (after some changes in the BIOS, I can't remember exactly which, unfortunately), I got the Syslinux menu, though, followed by the blank/black screen as described. No further clues, alas.

Comment: Yep, that's the Syslinux menu, not the GRUB menu. Have you tried removing all kernel parameters before booting (boot without 'quiet splash')?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to boot with all kernel parameters removed. Still nothing.

Comment: It looks like I am able to install OpenSuse (but that's not what I want/need), so it seems it is an Ubuntu-specific issue (erm, Ubuntu-AcerE15-specific issue).

Doesn't anyone have a clue or a suggestion how to continue pinpointing the problem? A black screen is not a very helpful starting point. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 when you get the black screen? Have you already tried the Ubuntu mini.iso?

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions, Eduardo. I did try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1: nothing, no console.

I just tried the Ubuntu mini-iso as well, but (as already stated at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) this did not work in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [was given in the Acer community](http://community.acer.com/t5/Linux/Ubuntu-on-E5-573G-71L9-black-screen-after-menu-on-Live-USB/m-p/405777/highlight/false#M44): "Have you installed the latest BIOS?"

Updating the BIOS from version 1.25 to 1.31 did the trick indeed. The reason is that [version 1.25 did not support Linux at all](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-and-M-Series/Acer-Aspire-e5-573g-You-can-not-install-any-one-Linux/td-p/386009) (probably a bug).

It still did not work out of the box: I had to manually add \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi to the boot sequence in order to get the GRUB menu (the entry was not automatically added).

So now I have a working Ubuntu environment. But... the wireless lan is not working. I will have to look into that tomorrow, but looking at the first quick search results, it seems that the network card is not supported...